# Signed but Unencrypted HTTP Traffic

Tags: encryption, tls, http, caching

A lot of the web is moving to HTTPS, which to my understanding does two things: Making the data unreadable by third parties, and verifying it's coming from the expected sender.
The latter seems unarguably good, but the first also has some downsides.

The noticeable downside I see is that it completely disables any more centralized caching (the browser itself could still cache). I am wondering if it would be possible to have HTTP traffic that is signed, so that no MitM could alter the data, but not encrypt it so that parties like CDN, the ISP or just the local network admin could configure it to be cached and significantly speed up the requests, and also decrease load on the origin servers.

---

I can see this is not for every application applicable, but for more static and insensitive data like for example Debian ISO download, Wikipedia or jQuery library files this could be used.

Would signed but unencrypted HTTP be possible? Is there a real use for this or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't understand. Cached content would be fetched once from the source. There would not be great savings to have that single fetch unencrypted.

Comment: @schroeder 
That would be true for just one device to the origin server, but not for hops in between. If I download a large static file like Debian ISO on my laptop in my office, and a colleague downloads the same file an hour later, they would not be able to use any cached version. If the office has a cache server locally setup, then with unencrypted data it could cache it, but not if the data is encrypted.

Comment: How would your cache server know what you were downloading in order to serve a cached version unless it broke the encryption first? Once it is broken then the connection to the target source doesn't need to be not encrypted. It already knows.

Comment: @schroeder I am not entirely sure what you are asking in regards of breaking encryption, I am assuming encrypted data can't be broken. The cache server knows which cache to server based on the requested URL.
1. The user requests the file (httpX://debian.org/iso.iso), through the cache server, but first a miss.
2. The origin server sends this data, with a signature that it is the original owner, to the cache server, which both streams it to the user, and puts it in the cache (both the file and the signature).
3.  A second user requests the file from the cache and verifies the signature.

Comment: If the connection would be signed but not encrypted would not make any difference because not just the content but the connection would be "signed" and any cache server would still break the authenticity of the connection and thus the client would have to assume it is a Mitm attack and throw an error.

Comment: A CDN and a caching server breaks the encryption between the client and the server. Encryption terminates on the mid-point and is (sometimes) reformed between the mid point and the target server. This is a normal process. That allows them to know what they can serve. A caching server will have ***no idea*** what file is being requested from the URL because the path will be encrypted.

Comment: @Robert How would an cache server break authenticity? A cache server on a cache hit would serve the file, alongside the signature, with which the authenticity can be confirmed by the client. Even though the current connection is not with the origin server, the client can confirm it originally came from the origin server by checking the signature to a certificate.

Comment: You asked for a signed HTTP connection not for a plain text connection serving files plus signature. Data authenticity and integrity can only be guaranteed by a signed protocol. Otherwise a mitm could simply return that a certain existing file on the server does not exist.

Comment: @Robert Excuse me for not understanding the difference or using the terms vaguely interchangably. I meant it in a theoretical sense that a plaintext file is accompanied with a signature, whether the protocol does that in headers or adding it otherwise to the flow of data. What I then expect the client that understands this "new" http protocol to do (be it the cache server or local client) to confirm the data has a signature made with the private key of the origin server (by decrypting it with the public key). If a MitM (rogue cache server) would change the data, the signature would fail.

Comment: And that is why your protocol is insecure: a mitm can change any request and always return "this file does not exist" because no data has no signature. Also if the filename is not included in the signature you could exchange any returned file. In the end you have a protocol that is vulnerable to many attacks which makes it IMHO useless.

Comment: The request URL could be confirmed in the data and therefore be signed. Also if a file does not exist or is empty it can still be signed by for example making this the signed data: "url: debian.org/wrong, data: no file is found" and hash and sign this. So this seems pretty easily solvable to me. Btw, thank you for the comments, I hope I am understanding correctly and enjoy trying to learn more about this.

Answer (score 4):

There is a standards draft called [Signed HTTP Exchanges](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/signed-exchanges/) that allows authors to sign and package contents. Third-parties then can serve the contents, while users are still able to verify its integrity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This definitely does look like it relates to my question, but it does seem to be focused on prefetching and very temporarily keeping the data. It is a maximum of 7 days cachable, and it is mainly used by resources that link to the data-in-question. It seems unlikely to be usable by caching software.

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly what you asked for, just something that answers the question "Would signed but unencrypted HTTP be possible?" so I thought it might be worth mentioning.